# Autoincremento al agregar registro en Realm de Android

Tags: java, android, realm

En realm veo que no hay nada como Mysql poder asignar autoicremento de un indice.
Cómo se podría realizar algo parecido al entrar nuevos registros.

Estructura `User` extendida `RealmObject`

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String TEAM_COLOR = "teamColor";
    public static final String LEVEL = "level";

    @PrimaryKey @Index
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private String teamColor;
    private int level;

    public long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getTeamColor() { return teamColor; }
    public void setTeamColor(String teamColor) { this.teamColor = teamColor; }
    public int getLevel() { return level; }
    public void setLevel(int level) { this.level = level; }
}
```

Para insertar datos lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            User entry = realm.createObject(User.class);
            entry.setId(1); // aquí se indica el indice
            entry.setName("user1");
            entry.setTeamColor("red");
            entry.setLevel(23);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra opcion de realizarlo es validando el null como si fuera el 0 :

```
        User entry = realm.createObject(User.class);
        int idNext = realm.where(User.class).max(User.id).intValue();
        if (idNext != null) {
            entry.setId(idNext + 1); // aquí se indica el indice
        } else {
            entry.setId(1); // aquí se indica el indice
        }

        entry.setName("user1");
        entry.setTeamColor("red");
        entry.setLevel(23);
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno tengo otra alternativa, algo mas sencilla..

```
public static int getUltimoId() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    Number number = realm.where(Empresa.class).max("id");
    return number == null ? 0 : number.intValue() + 1;
}
```

Éste método devuelve el último id de mi Clase Empresa..entonces cada vez que quiero crear un nuevo registro, llamaría a mi método estático así..

```
        Empresa empresa = realm.createObject(Empresa.class);
        empresa.setId(Empresa.getUltimoId())..
```

Comment: Tiene muy buena pinta, veo que también contempla si la tabla está vacía, gran optimización.

Comment: En realidad tu código y el mío hacen lo mismo XD

Answer (score 0):

Una manera para integrar sistema de autoincremento en realm, es obtener el valor máximo del indice y incrementar +1.

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        User entry = realm.createObject(User.class);

        // increatement indice
        int nextID = (int) realm.where(User.class).max(User.ID).intValue() + 1;

        entry.setId(nextID);
        entry.setName("user1");
        entry.setTeamColor("red");
        entry.setLevel(23);
    }
});
```

Si no hay ningún registro entrado a la tabla, devolverá error.
Para solventarlo:

```
int nextID = 0;
if (realm.where(User.class).findAll().size() > 0) {
    nextID = (int) realm.where(User.class).max(User.ID).intValue() + 1;
}
```

Es menos optimo, en cada nueva entrada se comprueba si hay registros.